# SSAS Tabular - dimension records of special interest

Tags: ssas-tabular, dimensional-modeling

I have a dimension with 700K entries.  10 of these are special interest to the client and will be frequently used in queries and as such need to be quickly retrieved.  Do I:
a) add an attribute to the dimension that flags these records, or
b) adopt a snowflake schema and add another dimension with the 10 records in it and attach it to the 700K dimension (effectively a 1 to 1 optional), or
c) add a new dimension with the 10 and attach it to the fact (but I need to obtain information from the 700K table - unless I denormalise the solution further and duplicate the attributes in the new dimension as part of ETL)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always go for option a), because it's the simplest and most intuitive solution to users. Only instead of adding a flag attribute, I prefer to create a "VIP" version of the main attribute (if possible). For example, let's say your dimension is "Customer", and it contains "Customer Name". I'd create a new attribute "Special Customer Name", list there names of special interest customers, and replace the rest with "Other" or something like that. Such design looks great on the reports, and easy to implement.

I always avoid snowflake design as much as possible. It's inferior in performance, and non-intuitive to users. The only justifiable case were I'd use it - if I need to share a dimension between fact tables with different granularity.

The third option is rather ugly conceptually. I'd consider it only if a dimension is too large (several million entries), and kills the performance of the entire star schema.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.  I found a technical document from M$ that details the maths engine in tabular and the algorithms employed and from that reached the same conclusion as your post.  Strategy seems to be star and minimum dimensions and the added attribute is low cardinality (the numbers 1 to 10 twice, all else 0 - so a tinyint) so will be highly compressed.  Thanks again for the response and the detailed reasoning as to why that option and not the others.

Comment: The article I was referring to is "Modeling for AS Tabular scalability" by Daniel Rubiolo.